# Flutter: How create event with Calendar Api without "clientViaUserConsent"?

Tags: android, flutter, calendar

My code is:

```
Future<dynamic> insertEvent(CalendarStore calendarStore) async {
  //criando calendário
  v3.Calendar request = v3.Calendar();
  request.summary = "APP";

  Map<String, String> eventData;

  String calendarId;
  v3.Event event = v3.Event();

  //some code creating event

  try {
    await clientViaUserConsent( //here 
            calendarStore.clientID, calendarStore.scopes, prompt)
        .then((AuthClient client) {

      var calendar = v3.CalendarApi(client);

      //some code here
     
    });
  } catch (e) {
    print('Error creating event \n\n\n$e');
  }

  return eventData;
}
```

This is my code, but it request authorization for the user all the time, my code also has GoogleSignIn code, is there any way to create the events without request authorization for the user every time?